# My application with Spinner not working, NullPointerException, what do I need to fix?

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, spinner

Debug Message:

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.notekeeper, PID: 6103
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notekeeper/com.example.notekeeper.NoteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.example.notekeeper.NoteActivity.onCreate(NoteActivity.java:35)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

My Code:

public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Spinner spinnerCourses = findViewById(R.id.spinner_courses);

    List<CourseInfo> courses = DataManager.getInstance().getCourses();
    ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo> adapterCourses =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courses);
    adapterCourses.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCourses.setAdapter(adapterCourses);
}
```

How do I fix this. The app doesn't open and simply crashes due to the fatal error.

Comment: This `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference at com.example.notekeeper.NoteActivity.onCreate(NoteActivity.java:35)` points right to the problem line of code.  I'd say `spinner_courses` is not part of your layout, therefore spinnerCourses variable is null.

Comment: @CSmith Android now defaults with two fragments in the layout. My spinner is in the first_fragment.xml but this setContentView calls my main_ctivity.xml. The first_fragment.xml is displayed in the main_activity.xml but the spinner component in in my first_fragment.xml. Do I need to SetContentView to first_fragement.xml instead?

Comment: Your code loads `R.layout.activity_note` for layout, then attempts to `findViewById(R.id.spinner_courses)` from this layout, and the stack trace indicates that this has returned null, as a crash occurs when calling `spinnerCourses.setAdapter(adapterCourses)`.  Lots of info is available online to help you learn how to debug an Android app, e.g. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug.